# Uploading mp4 files using PHP error

Tags: php, video, upload

I'm trying to upload an mp4 file, although it won't go through. I can upload any image type so long as I put the format in, but any video format what so ever doesn't work. Mp4, mov, etc.
This is the code I'm using to upload mp4

```html
<?php

    session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"]) or !is_array($_SESSION["user"]) or empty($_SESSION["user"])) {
      // redirect to login page
}



$target_dir = ('../MEDIA/films/');
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image


// Check if file already exists

// Check file size

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "MP4" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only MP4, MOV, M4V, MKV & AVI files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo header('Location: main.php');
    } else {
    echo header('Location: main.php');
    }
}
?>
```

And my form code is:

```html
<div class="container auth">
    <div id="big-form" class="well auth-box">
    <form class="form-horizontal"  action="video-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>

          <!-- Form Name -->
          <legend>Uploading as <?= $_SESSION["user"]["firstname"] ?></legend>

          <!-- Textarea -->
               <div class="form-group">
            <div class="">              
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
            </div>
          </div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <button id="updateprofile" value="Upload Video" name="updateprofile" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Be more specific?Do you get an error?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes.
I tried print_r and I got "Array () "
And this is the error: 
Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

Comment: One way to check for size `$size=filesize($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your video files are just too large. Check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in you `php.ini`, if possible.

Comment: Ah found it, used phpinfo and the max upload size is 20mb xD